# Travis + Tox, use matrix with different dependencies and commands

Tags: django, travis-ci, tox

I have the following travis/tox configuration and it works fine.  However, what I'd like to do is use the defined django/python matrix to run another set of tests which require a different test command and a different requirements file.

How to go abut this please?  Thanks,

travis.yml

```
env:
  matrix:
    - TOX_ENV=py27-django16
    - TOX_ENV=py27-django17
    - TOX_ENV=py27-django18
    - etc..
```

tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py{27,33}-django{16,17,18}

[testenv]
deps =
  -rrequirements.txt
  django16: Django<1.7
  django17: Django<1.8
  django18: Django<1.9

commands =
  python manage.py test
```